# Angular - convert expression value based of set values

Tags: angularjs, regex

I am trying to change the value of an expression based off an object of options

Currently I have an expression {{ resultItem.OdometerUnit }} which returns a total of 3 variations depending on result type

- hours
- kilometers
- miles

I want to first check whats returned to expression, and then convert the value to a shorthand version based off the below values

- hrs
- kms
- ms

I am thinking to do this using an object as follows:

```
  $scope.odometerUnitsTranslate = [
        { name: 'Kilometers', trans:'Kms' },
        { name: 'Hours', trans:'Hrs' },
        { name: 'Miles', trans:'Ms' }
  ];
```

Beginner with angular so not sure best approach. Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You could consider writing a custom [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to do the formatting for you. Usage might look like: `{{ resultItem.OdometerUnit | units }}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS

```
  $scope.odometerUnitsTranslate = 
        {'Kilometers':'Kms',
         'Hours': 'Hrs' ,
         'Miles': 'Ms' 
        };
```

HTML

```
  {{odometerUnitsTranslate[unit]}}
```

Comment: To handle missing translations, I'd slightly modify it to `{{odometerUnitsTransalate[unit] || unit}}`. That way, if something different comes up ("feet" for example), you get "feet" instead of nothing